# Is there a way to use `.well-known/openid-configuration` with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I see in the examples defining a provider as follows

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.authorization-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.token-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-info-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/userinfo?schema=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-name-attribute=name
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-info-authentication-method=header
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.jwk-set-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/jwks
```

Is there a property that would just let me do

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.openid-configuration=https://keycloak/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the property you are looking for is [spring-security 5.2.12.RELEASE - Spring Boot 2.x Property Mappings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-boot-property-mappings)

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.[providerId].issuer-uri
```

> A ClientRegistration can be initially configured using discovery of an OpenID Connect Provider’s Configuration endpoint or an Authorization Server’s Metadata endpoint, by specifying the spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.[providerId].issuer-uri property.

For a resource-server it would be
[spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html)

```
spring:
 security:
   oauth2:
     resourceserver:
       jwt:
         issuer-uri: https://idp.example.com/issuer
```

With the note

> To use the issuer-uri property, it must also be true that one of idp.example.com/issuer/.well-known/openid-configuration, idp.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/issuer, or idp.example.com/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server/issuer is a supported endpoint for the authorization server. This endpoint is referred to as a Provider Configuration endpoint or a Authorization Server Metadata endpoint.